# Graphic adapter seems installed correctly but windows is using basic driver

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, windows-10-v1511

I have Windows 10 x64 Pro build 1511 with all latest updates.
My graphic adapter ( discrete ) is an ATI radeon HD 5450.
I have installed the latest drivers downloaded from AMD site.
But now under Device Manager i can see my graphic Adapter installed correctly , but when i click on Drivers Details , i get a message : **No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device**
When i right click on Desktop and go to Adapter properties , i see that Windows is using "**Microsoft Basic Display driver**".

[image: screenshoot]

How can i resolve this problem ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The latest AMD driver only works for newer cards starting with the Radeon HD 77xx cards, not the older HD5xxx cards.

You need to install this [special driver for the older HD5400 card](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-Software-Crimson-Edition-16.2.1-for-Non-GCN-Products-Release-Notes.aspx)

Comment: The driver that you've suggested has damaged my windows. Now when is starting , windows remain on a black screen with mouse cursor and a circle that is round forever. I can't start even on start mode.

Comment: turn the PC off during start for 3 times and you should get to the recovery options. Here use System Restore to go to the point before the driver was installed. Also before doing sch things, always create a backp.